# Draw vertical lines on surface of the circle

Tags: c#, xaml, skiasharp

I draw geometric shapes using skiasharp. They are mostly circles. If we have simple example, just like this:

```
using System;
using SkiaSharp;

void Draw(SKCanvas canvas, int width, int height)
{
    
        var circleBorder = new SKPaint
        {
            IsAntialias = true,
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Blue,
            StrokeWidth = 5
        };
        canvas.DrawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, 30, circleBorder);
}
```

we get a simple cirle.
I've looked at the skiasharp documentation and still haven't found a way to draw lines over the surface of a circle. Can anyone suggest how to add those lines. I am sending an example of a picture of what I need to draw. Any help is appreciated.

[image: vertical lines on surface of the circle]

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what do you mean by "drawing lines over the surface of a circle"? Is the example image EXACTLY what you are trying to achieve? is there any rule how do you want the lines to be distributed?

Comment: @Maku, I need to make a slightly more complex shape, but at the beginning with, I need to make it like in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description I'd go with something based on circle equation:

```
void Draw(SKCanvas canvas, int width, int height)
{
    var circleBorder = new SKPaint
    {
        IsAntialias = true,
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        Color = SKColors.Blue,
        StrokeWidth = 5
    };

    var radius = 30f;
    var cx = width / 2f;
    var cy = height / 2;

    // define x-wise range on circle where we want to draw lines
    // 0 means leftmost point, 1 - rightmost
    // 0 <= startX < endX <= 1
    var startX = 0.15f;
    var endX = 1f;
    // how many lines in above range
    var count = 4;
    // length of lines
    var lineLength = 40f;

    var step = (endX - startX) / (count - 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // R^2 = (x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 => sqrt(R^2 - (x-x0)^2) = |y-y0|
        // we consider here coords from perspective where (0,0) is the leftmost point on the circle
        // therefore x0 = radius, y0 = 0

        var x = (i * step + startX) * radius * 2f; // current x on circle
        var absy_y0 = MathF.Sqrt(2 * x * radius - x * x); // == MathF.Sqrt(radius * radius - (x - radius) * (x - radius));
        var y = -Math.Abs(absy_y0); // we want lines upwards so only care about the smaller solution to equation

        canvas.DrawLine(x + cx - radius, y + cy, x + cx - radius, y + cy - lineLength, circleBorder);
    }

    canvas.DrawCircle(cx, cy, radius, circleBorder);
}
```

You can parametrize the hardcoded values however you want. Result of the above code:

[image]

Comment: how can make y-axis rotation?

Comment: do you mean something like a 3d effect?

Comment: yes.. for example: i made circle with shadow effect (using SKImageFilter.CreateDropShadow() method) with lines falling perpendicular to the circle.. i'm trying to make that these lines rotate along the y axis..

Comment: I've never done non-affine transforms so I won't be able to quickly help, but there is a nice tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/3d-rotation